# Using ILifetimeScope inside IDialog

Tags: c#, autofac, botframework

I'm using Microsoft Bot Framework to create a Bot. I'm calling the dialog on POST to MessageController, like this:

```
using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(_scope, activity))
{
  var postToBot = scope.Resolve<IPostToBot>();
  await postToBot.PostAsync(activity, cancellationToken);
}
```

Inside my Dialog class, I need to use a Factory that uses this scope. The problem is get this scope inside the Dialog class.

If I inject ILifetimeScope on constructor, it works for the first time. But this type is not serializable (throws an error on BotFramework). So I have to mark this as non serializable, but I have no ways to get this scope again. I try to use the default WebApi DependencyResolver, but I need an AutoFac feature that resolves keyed services. If I resolve a ILifetimeScope from DependencyResolver, then it returns the "root" scope, and I need the nested scope (the same used on message controller).

I solved my problem keeping the scope in a variable static, but this is not elegant.

```
using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(_scope, activity))
{
  IocModule.CurrentScope = scope;

  var postToBot = scope.Resolve<IPostToBot>();
  await postToBot.PostAsync(activity, cancellationToken);
}
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to inject IComponentContext which will help you to resolve dependencies.

Take a look to the [DialogFactory](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers.BotAssets/Dialogs/DialogFactory.cs) class from the [ContosoFlowers](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers) sample. Also a take a look to the [ContosoFlowersDialogFactory](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers/Dialogs/ContosoFlowersDialogFactory.cs) class which implements the DialogFactory. In the [ContosoFlowersModule](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowersModule.cs) class you will see the registration of that factory.

```
builder.RegisterType<ContosoFlowersDialogFactory>()
       .Keyed<IContosoFlowersDialogFactory>(FiberModule.Key_DoNotSerialize)
       .AsImplementedInterfaces()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

The constructor expects the IComponentContext

```
public ContosoFlowersDialogFactory(IComponentContext scope)
```

Regarding referencing non-serializables services in your dialog, marking them as non-serializable is not the only way. You can also use the [FiberModule.Key_DoNotSerialize](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Fibers/FiberModule.cs#L59) to resolve the dependency. You can read more about the different ways to reference non-serializable services in this [Technical FAQ section](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/technical-faq/#how-can-i-reference-non-serializable-services-from-my-c-dialogs).

Comment: No worries. It's brand new and it was announced just a few days ago: https://blog.botframework.com/2016/09/26/new-bot-builder-sdk-samples-released/